# FirefoxDriverService is not available in Selenium Server

Tags: selenium, selenium-firefoxdriver

Why [FirefoxDriverService](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/html/T_OpenQA_Selenium_Firefox_FirefoxDriverService.htm) is not available in Selenium Server? `ChromeDriverService` is how ever, is there. What library has the `FirefoxDriverService` class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's called `GeckoDriverService`. :-/